# Python integers act strange in a loop

Tags: python, loops, integer

The integers in the loop act strange: Every time the integer is later called the integer is always the last in the loop.

```py
        for b in info:
            if y > config["height"] - 160:
                if g:
                    f = i
                    self.f = f
                g = False
                y -= 160 * f
                x += 200
                self.x = x
            self.button[i] = canvas.create_rectangle(50 + x, 1 + y, 100 + x, 51 + y, outline="white",
                                                     fill="white")
            self.frame[i] = canvas.create_rectangle(0 + x, 0 + y, 190 + x, 140 + y, outline="#cfcfcf",
                                                    fill="white")
            self.item[i] = canvas.create_image(100 + x, 26 + y, image=icons["store-pack"][i])
            self.name[i] = canvas.create_text(100 + x, 75 + y, text=b["name"], fill="#7f7f7f", anchor=CENTER)
            self.c_icon[i] = canvas.create_image(40 + x, 117 + y, image=icons["store-coin"], anchor=W)
            self.coins[i] = canvas.create_text(95 + x, 117 + y, text=b["coins"], fill="#7f7f7f", font=("helvetica", 18), anchor=CENTER)
            self.items[i] = i
            canvas.tag_bind(self.button[i], "<Motion>", lambda event: self.__on_motion(canvas, deepcopy(i)))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.frame[i], "<Motion>", lambda event: self.__on_motion(canvas, deepcopy(i)))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.item[i], "<Motion>", lambda event: self.__on_motion(canvas, deepcopy(i)))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.name[i], "<Motion>", lambda event: self.__on_motion(canvas, deepcopy(i)))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.c_icon[i], "<Motion>", lambda event: self.__on_motion(canvas, deepcopy(i)))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.coins[i], "<Motion>", lambda event: self.__on_motion(canvas, deepcopy(i)))

            canvas.tag_bind(self.button[i], "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.buy_selected(config, modes, root, stats, canvas))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.frame[i], "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.buy_selected(config, modes, root, stats, canvas))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.item[i], "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.buy_selected(config, modes, root, stats, canvas))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.name[i], "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.buy_selected(config, modes, root, stats, canvas))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.c_icon[i], "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.buy_selected(config, modes, root, stats, canvas))
            canvas.tag_bind(self.coins[i], "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.buy_selected(config, modes, root, stats, canvas))
            y += 160
            i += 1
```

if the binded __on_motion is called it says i is always 23.
But I moved my cursor to another object with another index.
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: What integer? Where did `i` come from? It doesn't look you you pasted all your code.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Why should I copy ca. 1000 lines of code to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, with replace every `lambda event: ...` with `lambda event, i=i: ...`